# Install gem on demand

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I would like to install a gem (JSON) on the client side, but only if hasn't been installed already (some 1.9 Ruby distros have JSON bundled).

I couldn't find a clue on how to do that from `gem help install`. And running `gem install json` on a Windows system with Ruby 1.9 installed (with JSON bundled) results in

```
    ERROR:  Error installing json:
    The 'json' native gem requires installed build tools.
```

-- it tries to install it *ignoring* the fact that the gem is already there.

And I can't do bash tricks like grepping `gem list` output because the client might be Windows.

So what's the multiplatform way of installing a gem only if it's not present in the system already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work...

```
begin
  require "json"
rescue LoadError
  system("gem install json")
end
```

If you don't want to require "json", you can remove it from $LOAD_PATH.

Or, put as a one liner:

```
ruby -e 'begin; require "some_gem"; rescue LoadError; system "gem install some_gem"; end'
```

Comment: Great, will test it tomorrow and accept your answer as it seems to be the working solution. The only issue is that 'json' can be actually provided by two gems - json_pure and just json, so depending on the variant you need you would do `require 'json/ext'` or `require 'json/pure'` instead.

Comment: Yeah. Actually I think this is not the best way since we have to manually remove the path from $LOAD_PATH. It would be better if json/ext or json/pure is not actually included.

Comment: I'm executing the one-liner from the command line so I don't need to remove anything, so that's what I really needed thanks!

Comment: You forgot to add ```require "json"``` after the gem install. so:
`begin
  require "json"
rescue LoadError
  system("gem install json")
  require "json"
end`

Answer (score 2):

To ask if a gem is installed:

```
gem list --installed "^json$"
```

To install a gem if it's needed:

```
ruby -e '`gem list -i \"^json$\"`.chomp=="true" or `gem install json`'
```

To make a command line script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
# Ruby script to install a gem if it's needed.
# This script first uses gem list to see if the
# gem is already installed, matching the exact name.
#
# If the gem is installed, then exit.
# If the gem is not installed, then install it.
#
# You can this script whatever you like;
# I call mine gem-install-fast because it's
# faster than re-installing a gem each time.
# 
# Example:
#
#    gem-install-fast json
#
name=ARGV[0] and `gem list -i "^#{name}$"`.chomp=="true" or `gem install #{name}`
```

To use the command line script:

```
gem-install-fast json
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gem update json
```

should only install if necessary, on my windows 7 system it does

```
C:\Ruby193\bin>gem update json
Updating installed gems
Updating json
Fetching: json-1.6.6.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed json-1.6.6
Updating multi_json
Fetching: multi_json-1.2.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed multi_json-1.2.0
Gems updated: json, multi_json
Installing ri documentation for json-1.6.6...
Installing ri documentation for multi_json-1.2.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for json-1.6.6...
Installing RDoc documentation for multi_json-1.2.0...

C:\Ruby193\bin>gem update json
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update

C:\Ruby193\bin>
```

Comment: If you try to do `gem update` a gem that is not installed - it will fail

Comment: the screenshot from above proves me right, i didn't have the gem installed the first time, it installed and the second time it didn't

Answer (score 0):

The best I found is this (shell command):

`$ gem install asciidoctor --conservative`

It will install only if gem spec cannot be covered by currently installed gems.